# What is the recommended folder to put Design Pattern Classes

Tags: c#, design-patterns

In VS 2010 Web application, I have few design pattern classes `Singleton` & `Factory` etc, currently residing in `Util Folder`. Would it be correct to move them into App_Code folder.

As per the layered architecture what is the recommended place to put them into ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different teams have different naming / structure conventions.  I have seen **Util** folder used, **Helper** folder etc - just check with the team where they would all be happy to house the files.

Also, as you mentioned APP_CODE, are you using **Web Project** instead of **Web Application**?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It's *absolutely* up to **you**, or up to the dev-group to decide ho to design layout of these kind of files.

So feel free to pick the most approriate layout for **you**.

Comment: Indeed, if they are so non-application specific that they are named for the patterns they partially implement (names would be bad is they are specific) they don't really belong in a application, but in a shared library.

Comment: @Richard: a matter of arhitect choice. In software there are no *rules*, but *guides*. You are free to follow them or do no for your convinience.

Answer (score 1):

You should structure them in your application as they conform to the model they ultimately represent. There's no pre-defined 'right way' to do it. The system you're modelling is the driving force.